# How can I know what exceptions can be thrown from a method?

Tags: java, exception

How can I know what exceptions might be thrown from a method call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the `throws` clause of a method signature to see what "checked" exceptions could be thrown. Callers of the method will have to propagate this information in their own `throws` clause, or handle the exception.

There is no 100% reliable way to know what `RuntimeException` or `Error` types can be thrown. The idea is that these types are unlikely to be recoverable. It is common to have a high-level exception handler act as a "catch-all" to log, display, or otherwise report the `RuntimeException`. Depending on the type of application, it might exit at that point, or keep running.

Some APIs do document runtime exceptions they might throw with JavaDoc tags, just like a checked exception. The compiler does not enforce this, however.

In general, an `Error` is not caught. These indicate something seriously wrong with the runtime, such as insufficient memory.

Answer (score 2):

You read the 'throws' clause.

There is no way to tell what *unchecked* exceptions might get thrown.

If your *program* wants to know this, use reflection to reflect upon the 'throws' list.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the method declaration (or Javadoc). It will list all the *checked exceptions* which can be thrown from that method.

Any method can throw any *unchecked exception*.

Checked exceptions are any exceptions derived from `java.lang.Exception` (and including `Exception` itself) except `java.lang.RuntimeException` and its subclasses. Unchecked exceptions are types derived from `Throwable` (including `Throwable`) which *don't* derive from `Exception`, apart from `RuntimeException` and its subclasses. No, this wasn't particularly well thought out...

Comment: in the javadoc. it says Exceptions in the left. Is that unchecked or checked exceptions? and in the class content page after Throws, are those unchecked or checked exceptions?

Comment: You can declare that a method throws exceptions whether it's checked or not. I'm not sure what you mean about "in the left".

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/ if you click on a package then under it you can find the contents. classes, exceptions and errors. what kind of exceptions do they mean, checked or unchecked? if its checked, where can i find the runtime exceptions?

Comment: They're checked or unchecked as per the rules I said above - if they derive from `RuntimeException` or don't derive from `Exception`, they're unchecked - otherwise they're checked.

Answer (score 2):

Checked exceptions -- those that *do not* extend from RuntimeException -- are declared on method signatures and must be caught or declared on the signatures of other methods that use those methods.  The compiler makes these checks and will not complete the build if these principals are violated.

*Unchecked* exceptions -- RuntimeException and subclasses -- are not declared and may be thrown by any method.

That said, if your method commonly throws an unchecked exception it's a good idea to document that fact in javadoc.

If you need to catch anything that *might* be thrown within your method, you can always catch Exception or Throwable.  This approach is common at the boundaries of general-purpose libraries or APIs, allowing them to wrap outgoing exceptions in a standard type and include API-specific error information.

Comment: what do subclasses mean in "runtimeexception and subclasses"?

Comment: where do i have a list of all unchecked exceptions?

Comment: @Ajsie: "and subclasses" means "and subclasses of RuntimeException".

Answer (score 1):

For checked exception, the "throws" on the method call will tell you the whole story.

Unchecked exceptions are a little harder. Essentially you need to draw a tree of all methods called by the method and draw up a list of all unchecked exceptions that any one of them may call.

This will of course include anything that's thrown but not caught in those classes, and it will of course also include methods from the Java standard library plus any other libraries in your project.

So: If you really, really want to know you can but it could involve a bit of work.

Comment: @Carl - unchecked exceptions are more complicated than that.  Consider NullPointerException and OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: * nod * Right you are. And hand-checking for NPE is fiendishly difficult, for OOM is impossible. That's why we have full-scale testing, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

For checked exceptions, simply look at the signature of the method.  If the signature declares that the method `throws` an exception, then the method (or a method override in subclass) *might* throw the exception or a subclass of the exception.

For unchecked exceptions, any unchecked exception could in theory be thrown by any method call.  (You can add `throws` for an unchecked exception to a method signature, but this is redundant as far as the compiler is concerned.  The `throws` would serve only as documentation.)

The only way to get a more definitive answer would be to use some (hypothetical) source code or byte code analyser.  For example, you could determine that certain exceptions are never thrown or propagated by a method by simply checking that there are no instances of `new SomeException(...)` in the complete codebase.   But for some exceptions (e.g. NullPointerException and OutOfMemoryException) this analysis would be intractable except in very limited cases.

Comment: so the Exceptions on the left side of javadoc means runtime exceptions?

Comment: Not sure which you're talking about, but Javadoc only documents the checked exceptions, sorry.

Comment: @Ajsie - the exception for a method in the javadoc are the exceptions that the method signature declares that it `throws`.

Comment: @Carl - are you sure about that?  I'm pretty sure I can find examples in the Sun java of unchecked exceptions documented.

Comment: i mean on the left bottom frame in javadoc. above Errors we got Exceptions. Are these unchecked or checked (runtime) exceptions?

Comment: You mean like http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-frame.html ? The classes listed under the "Exceptions" heading are checked and unchecked Exception classes.  Notice that there is a separate "Errors" heading for the Error classes.  In conventional Java terminology (e.g. the JLS), the term "exception" in lower case refers to instances of both Exception and Error classes / subclasses.